# angular component DOM add attribute key

Tags: angularjs

I'am looping on DOM element  of angular component with ngfor like that

```
  <td>  
     <button class="dropdown-item" idgroup={{compte_ingroup}} href="#">
       action
     </button>

 </td>
```

my question is about to know how to add reference to element create in loop.
this issue happen to me  ==> Can't bind to 'idgroup' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

please what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is confusing... but you should be able to use the $index to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a component which template is

```
<td>
...
</td>
```

you should provide a property to it called idgroup, and when you invoke that component should be something like this:

```
<app-mycomponent *ngFor="let myelement of elementsList" [idgroup]="myelement.idgroup"></app-movie>
```

and in the component definition:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() idgroup: any;

  ...
}
```